# Is the memory allocated by new operated consecutive?

Tags: c++

as the title says, I want to know in c++, whether the memory allocated by one new operation is consecutive...

Comment: Are you looking for the word 'contiguous'?

Comment: If however you want to see what a particular C++ program's memory structure actually is gdb it.

Comment: Instance, if you want to do a stack overflow exploit (props to the name of our site here) you can count on for a heap overflow the contents to be properly executed so it doesn't matter.  Even though as they say below, the physical address in memory is not consecutive in all instances.

Comment: Thank you Jonanthan Leffler for your word correcting. After looking up in Collins ditionary, it seems "consecutive" is used when talking about time and events, while "contiguous" when describing things are next to each other

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
BYTE* data = new BYTE[size];
```

In this code, whatever size is given, the returned memory region is **consecutive**. If the heap manager can't allocate consecutive memory of `size`, it's fail. an exception (or NULL in `malloc`) will be returned.

**Programmers will always see the illusion of consecutive (and yes, infinite :-) memory in a process's address space.** This is what virtual memory provides to programmers.

Note that programmers (other than a few embedded systems) always see virtual memory. However, virtually consecutive memory could be mapped (in granularity of 'page' size, which is typically 4KB) in physical memory in arbitrary fashion. That mapping, you can't see, and mostly you don't need to understand it (except for very specific page-level optimizations).

What about this?

```
BYTE* data1 = new BYTE[size1];
BYTE* data2 = new BYTE[size2];
```

Sure, you can't say the relative address of `data1` and `data2`. It's generally non-deterministic. It depends on heap manager (such as `malloc`, often `new` is just wrapped `malloc`) policies and current heap status when a request was made.

Comment: Whoa there. If `new` fails, it throws `std::bad_alloc`. It **never** returns NULL.

Comment: Sorry, confused. In old, Visual C++ implementation, it did return NULL, but now conforms C++ standard. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftdy56f(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Infinite memory? I forget, what does that mean?

Comment: Infinite memory: more precisely, virtual memory gives an illusion of 2^32 or 2^64 address space. In this space, you generally don't need to consider the actual size of physical memory. Now, 32-bit address space is very limited, however, 64-bit space is technically *infinite*. (But, current x864-64 processors do not support full 64-bit virtual address space. Usually 46-bit or so.)

Comment: @rlbond - never say never.  Besides older compilers (and VC6 is still pretty widely used), there's the `std::nothrow` overload for `new` that can return 0 for failure. Just bringing up a stupid bit of trivia.

Answer (score 7):

The memory allocated in *your process's address space* will be contiguous.

How those bytes are mapped into physical memory is implementation-specific; if you allocate a very large block of memory, it is likely to be mapped to different parts of physical memory.

**Edit:**  Since someone disagrees that the bytes are guaranteed to be contiguous, the standard says (3.7.3.1):

> The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage.  If it is successful, it shall return the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes shall be at least as large as the requested size.

Comment: So the corollary is: yes, you can treat them as consecutive (even if you really don't know if they are).

Comment: this is wrong -- you have no guarantee of ordering in or out of your process.

Comment: so you mean that the memory our program using is virtual memory? and the virtual memory is mapped from physical memory by OS(while this mapping mechanism is implemation-specific?)?

Comment: so...if all the program is using physical memory physically, why some one says memory newed-out is consecutive,while others says it's not?
And I'm very much confused by deleting the inconsecutive memory...

Comment: Except a few embedded system, you can't simply play with physical memory.

Comment: minjang, I know that the memory is allocated by OS via new operater. But my confusion is I don't know whether this right memory I use by one new operation is consecutive or not. As far from the comments, it seems that I have to know much about the memory allocation of specific OS. And still I don't know whether I can assume the memory allocated by one new operation consecutive or not.

Comment: Simply, it is **consecutive**. Believe me. You don't mostly need to know the details of memory allocation. You don't even need to see the value of pointers.

Comment: Again (please see my answer), **virtual memory** gives (1) consecutive and (2) infinite illusion of memory. Yes, infinite is not true, 2^32/2^64 or 2^31 etc..

Comment: ok...thank you you all...this rises me to read some books about operating system...:)

Comment: Single allocations are contiguous, but the process address space often isn't. A common example are platforms where the OS has a good memory allocator, and where new() can forward directly. On those platforms you typically have a heap for small allocations, but larger blocks are allocated directly by the OS. As a result, after one small and one big allocation, you will have 2 disjoint areas of memory.

Answer (score 4):

Case 1:
 Using "new" to allocate an array, as in

```
int* foo = new int[10];
```

In this case, each element of foo **will** be in contiguous virtual memory.

Case 2:
 Using consecutive "new" operations non-atomically, as in

```
int* foo = new int;
int* bar = new int;
```

In this case, there is never a guarantee that the memory allocated between calls to "new" will be adjacent in virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

The virtual addresses of the allocated bytes will be contiguous. They will also be physically contiguous within resident pages backing the address space of your process. The mapping of physical pages to regions of the process virtual space is very OS and platform specific, but in general you cannot assume physically contiguous range larger then or not aligned on a page.

Answer (score 1):

If by your question you mean "Will successive (in time) new() operations return adjacent chunks of memory, with no gaps in between?", this old programmer will suggest, very politely, that you should not rely on it.

The only reason that question would come up was if you intended to walk a pointer "out" of one data object and "into" the next one.  This is a really bad idea, since you have no guarantee that the next object in the address space is of anything remotely resembling the same type as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Don't bother about the "virtual memory" issue: apart that there could be cases when you haven't at all a system that supports virtual memory, from **your** PoV you get a consecutive memory chunk. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Physical memory is never contiguous its logical memory which is contiguous.