# Create 2d or 3d array using one dynamically allocated memory block

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a two dimensional array that I've allocated dynamically using new.

The problem is I want to allocate the memory as one connected block instead of in separated pieces to increase processing speed.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this with new, or do I have to use malloc?

Here's my code:

```
A = new double*[m];
    for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        A[i]= new double[n];
    }
```

**This code causes a segmentation fault**

```
phi = new double**[xlength];
phi[0] = new double*[xlength*ylength];
phi[0][0] = new double[xlength*ylength*tlength];
for (int i=0;i<xlength;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<ylength;j++)
    {
        phi[i][j] = phi[0][0] + (ylength*i+j)*tlength;
    }
    phi[i] = phi[0] + ylength*i;
}
```

Comment: Consider making a `Matrix` class out of it that represents 2D operations with a 1D array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719607/is-the-memory-allocated-by-new-operated-consecutive  look at this.

Comment: @bill, that didn't answer my question, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @Mechy I know it is not an exact match, but thought you would be interested....since it is somewhat related.

Comment: Why not use the standard container classes?

Comment: Hmm. Can `new` allocate a connected memory block in the same way `malloc` can, tell me (hint: allocating connected memory blocks is all `new` and `malloc` are about)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allocate one big block and use it appropriately, something like this:

```
double* A = new double[m*n];
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        A[i*n+j] = <my_value>;
    }
}
```

Instead of using `new`, you can use `malloc` - there is no much difference, except that `new` must be released with `delete`, and `malloc()` released with `free()`.

**UPDATE1**:
You can create "true" 2d array (with dimensions `m` x `n`):

```
double** A = new double*[m];
double*  B = new double[m*n];
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    A[i] = B + n*i;
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        A[i][j] = <my_value>;
    }
}
```

Just be sure to release both `A` and `B` in the end.

**UPDATE2**:

By popular request, this is how you can create "true" 3-dimensional array (with dimensions `m` x `n` x `o`):

```
double*** A = new double**[m];
double**  B = new double*[m*n];
double*   C = new double[m*n*o];
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    A[i] = B + n*i;
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        B[n*i+j] = C + (n*i+j)*o;
        for (int k=0; k<o; k++) {
            A[i][j][k] = <my_value>;
        }
    }
}
```

This uses 2 relatively small "index" arrays `A` and `B`, and data array `C`. As usual, all three should be released after use.

Extending this for more dimensions is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is a nice way to make a 1-dimensional array, but if I don't want to flatten my array, is it possible to make one big contiguous block of memory with new like you can do with malloc?

Comment: @Mechy, Don't quote me on this if I'm being crazy, but if you `new[]` up 20 `int`s of space, you might be able to get away with treating a pointer to it like a `int[4][5]` or `int[5][4]`. I'm not exactly sure if that's allowed. In any case encapsulating it in a `Matrix` class is much cleaner. You can just say `mat(i,j)`, but have it be a 1D contiguous chunk internally.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. I think somehow you are making B and A overlap by changing the addresses of A's memory to the first m addresses of B's memory, right? How are you doing that without pointers though? Also, does this create m blocks of "wasted space" memory from A?

Comment: `A` is relatively small array of pointers that point inside large `B`. The only wasted space is `A` itself, but it is small

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I assume this code won't scale though with rather large allocations of memory due to the wasted space, right? For example, using it for 3D arrays would make a lot of wasted space.

Comment: Again, there is NO wasted space, except for "index" array `A`. It will work for 3d, but you will have to create second level index, which should be relatively small still

Comment: Oh! Does my current code also create these indexes except uses a jagged array? Thank you for all your help by the way.

Comment: @Mechy: yes, your code will create a lot of overhead due to memory heap maintenance. This approach should be more efficient, even with 2nd and 3rd level indexes for 3d or 4d arrays.

Comment: Can I deallocate it simply by using delete[] A; delete[] B; or is a little trickier? Normally, I'd just use a for loop to deallocate my current code.

Comment: yes, this is exactly how you should deallocate: `delete[] A; delete[] B`;

Comment: Is there a way to implement this for 3 dimensions?

Comment: Doesn't that last example mix data types though? double** with double*? And go out of the scope of B (m*n)

Comment: No, I have tested this in `g++` - seems to work and no compilation warnings (added proper pointer types to the answer).

Comment: If you run it, you get a segmentation fault though. I'll post the code. never mind, it's perfect! Thank you

Comment: Something bothers me about your B[n*i+j] though. Doesn't that go out of the bounds of B[n*m]?

Comment: @Mechy *"This is a nice way to make a 1-dimensional array, but if I don't want to flatten my array, is it possible to make one big contiguous block of memory with new like you can do with malloc"* - Sorry, but what else is a 1-dimensional array than one big contiguous block of memory? If it is that you want to allocate one big-block of memory and treat it as a dynamic 2-dimensional array, then that's not possible (and I wonder who told you that `malloc` could do this). `new` behaves exactly like `malloc` in this regard.

Comment: @ChristianRau but this whole post was about how to do it...and it works.

Comment: @Mechy Still this isn't achieved by `new` or `malloc` directly, but by additional logic (which is absolutely no problem, but you would have to do that with `malloc` either). It was your differentiation between `new` and `malloc` that was wrong, since they're completely equivalent in this regard, they're all always just allocating a contiguous block of memory, not more and not less (well, `new` does more, but that's irrelevant for the question here).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do with `malloc` that you can't do with `new` (though the converse doesn't hold).  However if you've already allocated the memory in separate blocks, you will have to allocate new (contiguous) memory in order to get a connected block (with either `malloc` or `new`).  The code you show allocates `m` non-contiguous `n`-sized blocks.  To get an array with contiguous memory from this, you would need

```
int MN = m*n;
B = new double[MN];
for (int i=0; i<MN; ++i)
   B[i] = A[ i/N ] [ i%N ];
```

Comment: Does that mean it's one big block of memory already?
I thought that the thing would allocate the strips in different locations. For example   A<--here's strip A   ------------------------>Strip B is waaaaay over here instead of right next to A.

Comment: How do I fix that? I don't want it jagged.

Comment: @Mechy To get a contiguous block you just allocate a 1D array with MxN elements and then make sure that within the array, data is laid out row-by-row (row major) or column-by-column (column-major), your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if the task is to maintain a single block of memory, but keep [][] way of addressing it, I'd try a few tricks with classes. The first one is an inside proxy:

```
class CoordProxy
{
private:
    int coordX;
    int arrayWidth;
    int * dataArray;

public:
    CoordProxy(int * newArray, int newArrayWidth, int newCoordX)
    {
        coordX = newCoordX;
        arrayWidth = newArrayWidth;
        dataArray = newArray;
    }

    int & operator [](int newCoordY)
    {
        return (dataArray[newCoordY * arrayWidth + coordX]);
    }
};

class CoordsWrapper
{
private:
    int * dataArray;
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    CoordsWrapper(int * newArray, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        dataArray = newArray;
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
    }

    CoordProxy operator[] (int coordX)
    {
        return CoordProxy(dataArray, width, coordX);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int * a = new int[4 * 4];
    ZeroMemory(a, 4 * 4 * sizeof(int));

    CoordsWrapper w(a, 4, 4);

    w[0][0] = 10;
    w[0][1] = 20;
    w[3][3] = 30;

    std::for_each(&a[0], &a[4 * 4], [](int x) { printf("%d ", x); });

    delete[] a;
}
```

Note, that this is not time-efficient, but extremely memory efficient: uses 4 ints and 2 pointers more than original class.

There's even nicer and a lot faster solution, but you would have to resign from [][] notation in favor of (,) notation:

```
class CoordsWrapper2
{
private:
    int * data;
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    CoordsWrapper2(int * newData, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        data = newData;
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
    }

    inline int & Data(int x, int y)
    {
        return data[y * width + x];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int * a = new int[4 * 4];
    ZeroMemory(a, 4 * 4 * sizeof(int));

    CoordsWrapper2 w(a, 4, 4);

    w.Data(0, 0) = 10;
    w.Data(0, 1) = 20;
    w.Data(3, 3) = 30;

    std::for_each(&a[0], &a[4 * 4], [](int x) { printf("%d ", x); });

    delete[] a;
}
```

Note the inline directive. It suggests the compiler to replace the method call for actual source code, which make it a little faster. This solution is even more memory efficient and a either a tiny bit less or equally time efficient as classic indexing.