# Two Dimesional array in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm trying to pass the pointer value as parameter to two dimensional array, but it does not work? Here is an example:

```
void Pass(char *ch) // <--------- Where's I'm getting the error
{}

int main(...)
{
    char ch[5][5];
    Pass(ch);
}
```

How should I pass it correctly, as a parameter which is pointer to two dimensional array?

Comment: post your error please. the variable name by itself should point to the first element, so `ch == &ch[0][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, pointer to 2-dimensional array is basically the same as pointer to 1-dimensional array, and original sizes of 2-dimensional array are lost when passed as pointer (`char*` in your case).

You can either define your Pass function with explicit size definition:

```
void Pass(char ch[5][5]) {...}
```

Or pass sizes as additional parameters:

```
void Pass(char* ch, int size_x, int size_y) {...}
```

Second option is more dynamic, but requires more caution.
To access array at (x,y), use this formula:

```
ch[size_y * x + y]
```

While passing `size_x` may seem redundant, you will need it to limit your `x` from `0` to `size_x-1`, and `y` from `0` to `size_y-1`.

Comment: Passing an n-dimensional array always requires you to explicitly state the size of every other dimensions greater than 1. The second approach won't work.

Comment: it certainly would work and is more dynamic - it is not limited to fixed array sizes

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Um why would it not work? (apart from the fact that it should be passed as `&arr[0][0]` instead of `arr`)

Comment: @mvp "In C, pointer to 2-dimensional array is basically the same as pointer to 1-dimensional array" - that's wrong. Also, what do you mean by "more dynamic"? We have been using variable-length arrays for 14 years (they're standard in C99).

Comment: @H2CO3: well, it depends. In static context like in this question, this is true. If array bounds are not known (like `char**`), then ch[x][y] is completely different beast. Regarding dynamic arrays: C does not support defining dynamic array, but you can use `malloc` to allocate one. But that is again beyond scope of OP question

Comment: @H2CO3 I commented before an edit on the post was made, it was different before. Now, it works, but it's really ugly, easy to get wrong, and makes me wonder why we're using a compiler at all if we have to do this kind of thing by hand. And if you want to compile it without warnings, an ugly cast is needed to call that function with a 2D array.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves No cast is needed (in fact, that cast is wrong), it should just be passed as `function(&arr[0][0])` instead of `function(arr)`. Also, I'm not saying it is nice (I don't recommend it either), I'm just asserting that "it does not work" is not true. Yes, passing a true pointer-to-array is definitely preferred.

Comment: Take a look at this question, very entertaining to understand 2-d and 3-d arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555862/how-do-i-allocate-one-block-of-memory-with-new/16555923#16555923

Comment: @mvp Don't teach me C! I know that a pointer-to-pointer is not the same as a two-dimensional array. And I wasn't talking about a pointer-to-pointer either. It seems that **you** don't know that one can define variable-length arrays like this: `size_t x; x = some_value(); int arr[x];`. That's not the same as `malloc()`ating memory for each individual row.

Comment: @H2CO3: ANSI C does not support defining variable arrays. Some compilers like gcc may allow it, but it is not in standard.

Comment: @H2CO3 hum, didn't think about &arr[0][0]. Nice one.

Comment: @mvp You should read the C99 and C11 standards. We no longer live in 1989.

Comment: @mvp variable length arrays are allowed since C99. ANSI C is not the current C standard, C11 is.

Comment: this question is tagged C, not C++11 or C99, so we have to assume worst.

Comment: @mvp C11, not C++11. And no, if it's not tagged "C89", we are allowed to assume the use of the **current** standard.

Answer (score 1):

The array-to-pointer decayment rule is not recursive. Inside main(), ch is of type char (*)[5], i.e., pointer to array of 5 chars. Pass() is expecting a pointer to char, hence the error.

Therefore, Pass() should be declared as receiving char (*ch)[5].